# Adding a range to a Listbox

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, listbox

I have an array with about 5 items in it that I need to set in a listbox, lets say (5,1,71,221,453) and I want to just add them without making a whole For each or whatever loop.

Is there a way that I can set multiple items to a listbox at once in VB.net? without iterating through them?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange({5, 1, 71, 221, 453}.Cast(Of Object).ToArray)
```

If using an existing array, try:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(myarray.Cast(Of Object).ToArray)
```